# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{2} \frac{(1+t)^ne^{-nt}}{\frac{1}{n}+\ln{(1+nt^2)}}dt$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

As stated in the title, the problem is

> Evaluate $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{2} \frac{(1+t)^ne^{-nt}}{\frac{1}{n}+\ln{(1+nt^2)}}dt. $$

Since this is from a measure theory course, I'm supposed to solve this using the dominated convergence theorem, but I can't find an upper bound for $f_{n}$. The best I can do is a substitution $x = nt$, which yields $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^{2n} \frac{(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}e^{-x}}{1+n\ln{(1+\frac{x^2}{n})}}, $$

and I can't find an upper bound for this whose integral from $-n$ to $2n$ (actually, on $\mathbb{R}$ but multiplied by $\chi_{[-n,2n]}$) converges.

Comment: You can do as follows:$\frac{1}{n}+ln(1+nt^2)=ln e^{\frac{1}{n}}+ln(1+nt^2)=ln(1+nt^2) e^\frac{1}{n}$

$Lim_{n→∞}\int^2_{-1}\frac{(1+t)^n. e^{-nt}}{ln(1+nt^2) e^\frac{1}{n}}=\int^2_{-1}Lim_{n→∞}\frac{(1+t)^n. e^{-nt}}{ln(1+nt^2) e^\frac{1}{n}}==lim_{n→∞ }\int^2_{-1}\frac{(1+t)^n}{ln(1+nt^2)}$

Comment: How does writing $\frac{1}{n}$ as $\ln{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}$ help me bound the denominator? What I'm asking is, which integrable function $g(t)$ did you find such that $\frac{(1+t)^ne^{-nt}}{\frac{1}{n} + \ln{(1+t^2)}} \leq g(t)$ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hint: $(1+x/n)^n\le e^x$, $(1+x^2/n)^n\ge e^{x^2}/c$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice the second inequality... I think that hint pretty much solves it. Thanks! I'll try to write everything out now, I'll leave another comment with a question if I have any trouble, if it's no problem.

Comment: Actually, I think I'm not certain about the second inequality - particularly, for the choice of $c$. The problem is, because $(1+x^2/n)^n \to e^{x^2}$, we can say, for example, $(1+x^2/n)^n \geq e^{x^2}/2$ after $n_{0}(x)$, but the problem is, the $n_{0}$ after which the inequality starts to hold depends on the point $x$, so the estimate is not uniform. The $n_{0}(x)$'s could get arbitrarily large as we start to vary the $x$'s. So if we were to include $\ln{e^{x^2}/c}$ in the upper bound function $g$ instead of the corresponding $\ln{(1+x^2/n)^n}$, we wouldn't have $f_{n}(x)<g(x)$...

Comment: for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for all $x$.